# Chrome computes incorrect input color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm setting `color: white !important` on an input, but text color is wrong and in computed styles I see:

[image]

this drives me a bit crazy, has anyone seen this problem and are there any workarounds?

Currently I've hacked my way around this by setting `filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%);` which gives the whiteish color that I want, but I don't really like this solution.

Comment: Please share your relevant code.

Comment: color: white !important 

in css, that's all the relevant code

Comment: I have added an answer.Please check.

Comment: Check your Html file.color: black; must be there